# I want to insert multiple month's salary in an employee id. right now i can insert only one month's salary in one customer id

Tags: php, mysql

```
"employee" table has E_ID, E_Name, E_Address, E_Mail, E_Dept. [E_ID is primary key]

"salary" table has E_ID, S_Amount, S_Date columns.
```

Suppose an E_ID is 4001 and it is November month. I can only insert November month's salary into 4001 E_ID. But i want to insert December, January, February. all months salary into one E_ID and also want to view per month's salary. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the primary key on the `Salary` table? Schema and sample data would be good too.

Comment: What is your query ?

Comment: I made E_ID the primary key of salary table too. I am new here. any suggestion?

I am using this code to add salary into an E_ID-

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dhaka");

            $raw="date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka')";
            $raw=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            //$raw=date($op2);
            $date= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($raw));


            mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO salary(E_ID, S_Amount, S_Date) VALUES ('$a', '$s_am','$date')");
            
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM salary");

Comment: Your salary table shoud have S_ID as Primary key then E_ID as foreign key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Salary table , add a new column say 'id' set it as integer , primary key , auto-increment.

Do not make E_ID as primary column in Salary table. As you have defined it as a primary key , you can only able to insert it once. Primary key is a unique key table and does not repeated.

You may use this script

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `salary` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `E_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `S_Amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `S_Date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Here S_Amount column is Decimal type as it is used to store salary. You can use integer also

Comment: @rony We are glad. Please select his answer as "best answer" if this is the one which helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove primary key from `salary.E_ID`. A primary key requires every value in that column to be unique - that's why you can only enter one row for a particular employee. I imagine you can add a unique key to the columns `E_ID` and `S_Date` as you will likely only ever have one entry per month per employee.

Here's inserting multiple rows into a table,

```
INSERT INTO salary (E_ID, S_Amount, S_Date) 
VALUES
    (4001, 250.00, "2016-09"),
    (4001, 235.00, "2016-10"),
    (4001, 280.00, "2016-11")
```

I've made some assumtions with this example but it should explain the principle.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the table named "salary" does not has the E_ID as a primary key. It may enable you to enter many entries of salary of the same employee having the same E_ID.

Rather make the column E_ID in the "salary" table as foreign key so that you can check each month salary of a specific employee.

Comment: Thanks you :) I changed E_ID to foreign key. It is working.

Comment: @rony glad to know that I could help you out :)